# How to convert from mysqli to PDO with function that hides empty columns

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, html-table, sql-injection

I have an html-form to read out data from a DB that are then dislayed in an html-table. Columns that contain no values should not be displayed. This works well with the following code using array_column and array_filter:

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT $selection FROM $table WHERE $where";

$result = mysqli_query($db, $sql) or die("<b>No results</b>"); //Running  the query and storing it in result
$numrows = mysqli_num_rows($result);  // gets number of rows in result  table
$numcols = mysqli_num_fields($result);   // gets number of columns in  result table
$field = mysqli_fetch_fields($result); // gets the column names from the  result table 

$custom_column_arr = array('Color' => 'color_comment', 'Weight' => 'weight_comment');

if($numrows > 0) {

    echo "<table id='myTable'>";

    echo "<thead>";


    $results = array();

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $results[] = $row;
    }

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<th>" . 'Nr' . "</th>";

    for($x = 0; $x < $numcols; $x++) {
        $column[$x] = array_column($results, $field[$x]->name);  //  puts all existing values of a column into the field-name

        if(array_filter($column[$x])) {   //    displays only those columns with at least one value in it
            $key = array_search($field[$x]->name, $custom_column_arr);
            if($key !== FALSE) {
                echo "<th>" . $key . "</th>";
            } else {
                echo "<th>" . $field[$x]->name . "</th>";
            }
        }
    }
    echo "</tr></thead>";

    echo "<tbody>";

    $nr = 1;


    $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $nr . "</td>";
        for($k = 0; $k < $numcols; $k++) {    //  goes around until there are no columns left
            $column[$k] = array_column($results, $field[$k]->name);         //  puts  all existing values of a column into the field-name
            if(array_filter($column[$k])) {                               //    displays only those columns with at least one value in it
                echo "<td>" . $row[$field[$k]->name] . "</td>"; //Prints the data   } }   echo "</tr>";   $nr = $nr + 1;

            }     // End of while-loop
            echo "</tbody></table>";
        }
    }
    mysqli_close($db);
}
```

Due to security reasons, I switched to PDO prepared statements to avoid SQL-injection:

```
enter code here

$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT $selection FROM $table WHERE color = :color AND weight = :weight";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$renalstatus = '10';
$bindValue = implode("/n ", $bindValue);
$stmt->bindValue(':color', $color, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(':weight', $weight, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();

$zeilen = $stmt->rowCount();
$spalten = $stmt->columnCount();

if($zeilen > 0) {

    echo "<table id='myTable'>";

    echo "<thead>";


    $results = array();

    while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $results[] = $row;
    }

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<th>" . 'Nr' . "</th>";

    for($x = 0; $x < $spalten; $x++) {
        $column[$x] = array_column($results, $fields[$x]->name);          //  puts all existing values of a column into the field-name
        if(array_filter($column[$x])) {                              //       displays only those columns with at least one value in it
            $key = array_search($fields[$x], $custom_column_arr);
            if($key !== FALSE) {
                echo "<th>" . $key . "</th>";
            } else {
                echo "<th>" . $fields[$x] . "</th>";
            }
        }
    }
    echo "</tr></thead>";

    echo "<tbody>";

    $nr = 1;

    $stmt = $pdo->query($sql);

    while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM)) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $nr . "</td>";
        for($k = 0; $k < $spalten; $k++) {        //  goes around until there are     no columns left

            $column[$k] = array_column($results, $fields[$k]->name);         //      puts all existing values of a column into the field-name
            if(array_filter($column[$k])) {                               //       displays only those columns with at least one value in it
                echo "<td>" . $row[$k] . "</td>"; //Prints the data}
            }
            echo "</tr>";
            $nr = $nr + 1;


        }     // End of while-loop

        echo "</tbody></table>";
    }
}
$stmt->close();
```

The query results are correctly displayed as before. However, completely empty columns are displayed as well and shoul be hidden.
After having built the headline, in mysqli there is a second query before the rows are generated:

```
  $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
```

Unfortunately, using PDO this does not work with:

```
  $stmt = $pdo->query($sql); or $stmt->execute();
```

I would be more than happy if someone could help me make this function work again!

Comment: You don't *need* to switch. Mysqli has [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [bind_param](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php).

Comment: @aynber Thanks, are mysqli prepared Statements as safe as PDO prepared statements in regards to SQL-injection? And can I keep the code for the table generation as it is in this case?

Comment: Yes, they are just as safe.

Comment: As long as it's done properly.

Comment: And can I keep the code for the table generation as it is in this case?

Comment: It should be fine. Only one way to find out!